redirect url not working when users are signed in
i'm working on an app feature where users are to link their account details with a third party platform and then gets redirected back to our app after they are linked but users that are logged in don't get redirected but when tested with a user not logged in, the redirect url works. what can i do?
I made a post request by sending the redirect url as part of the parameter to our third party platform. the redirect url only works when users are not logged in to our app but doesn't when they are signed in
